# Query Mongo DB for all trajectories (lon/lat arrays) contained in a polygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, polygon

Consider a collection of trajectories with a field "location" formed by lon/lat arrays. How to query mongo db for all the trajectories completely contained in given polygon ?

I tried:

`pipeline = {"$match": {"location":{'$geoWithin'{'$geometry':myPolygon}}}}`

`db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)`

The code runs and gives some trajectories with points inside the polygon, however, many points remain outside. I also tried without results:

`{"$match": {"location":{"$not":{"$elemMatch":{"location":{"$not{'$geoWithin':{'$geometry':myPolygon}}}}}}}}`

`db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)`

Comment: GeiJSON are lon/lat - not lat/lon

Comment: Yes thanks, I am aware of that it was a typo